# Link in server response not clickable

Tags: php, hyperlink

I am trying to upload an image (user's profile picture) to my server using a simple HTML form and PHP.

## HTML

```
<?php include("../../header_init.php"); ?>  
<div class="PageContainer">
    <div class="PageTitle">Profile Initialization - Step 3 of 4</div>
    <div id="InitStepDisplay_Stretched">
        <p><span class="BigText">Display Image</span></p>
        <br />
        <div id="PictureDisplayInit"></div>
        <div id="Image_Upload_Instructions">
            <form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="../../UploadImage.php" target="ResponseArea" >
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="SmallText">The photo must be less than 2MB in size and of formats JPEG, PNG, GIF or BMP.</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input class="FileInput" type="file" name='file' id="file" accept="image/*" /></td>                         
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input class="Button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"></td>
                    </tr>                       
                </table>                    
            </form>
            <iframe name="ResponseArea"></iframe>
        </div>                              
    </div><!-- End of InitStepDisplay_Stretched -->             
</div><!-- End of div PageContainer -->
```

## PHP

```
if ($_FILES['file']['size'] > 0)
{
    $filename = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp", "jpeg","GIF","JPG","BMP","PNG");
    list($txt,$ext) = explode(".",$filename);
    if (in_array($ext, $valid_formats))
    {
        if ($size < 2098888)
        {
            // TO DO: Remove any older profile picture                      
            $clean_name = str_replace(" ", "_", $txt)."_".time().".".$ext;
            $query = "UPDATE tblSomething SET MyPicture = '" . $clean_name . "' WHERE CurrentUserID = " . $_SESSION['CurrUserID'];
            $update_tblSomething = $conn->query($query);
            if ($update_tblSomething == true)
            {
                $newname = 'images/profile/'.$clean_name;

                if ($_FILES['file']['error'] == 0 && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $newname))
                {
                    $uploaded = $newname;                           
                    echo("<img src='../../".$uploaded."'  class='PictureDisplayInit Stretch'> <input type='hidden' name='actual_image_name' id='actual_image_name' value='$uploaded' />");
                    $query = "UPDATE tblAnotherOne 
                                          SET Step3Complete = 1, LastUpdated = '" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "' WHERE CurrentUserID = " . $_SESSION['CurrUserID'];
                    $update_TPC = $conn->query($query);
                    if ($update_TPC)
                    {
                        echo "<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><span class='SuccessText'>File uploaded successfully. You're almost done.</span><br /><br /><a href='../step4/'>Proceed to final step</a>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "<script>location.href='../../error.php?code=3'</script>";                                 
                    }                               
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<span class='ErrorTextSmall'>Image could not be uploaded. Please try again.</span>";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                "<script>location.href='../../error.php?code=3'</script>";
            }                       
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "<span class='ErrorTextSmall'>File size exceeded 2MB! Please choose a smaller file.</span>";
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "<span class='ErrorTextSmall'>Invalid image file format. Only jpg, png, gif and bmp formats allowed.</span>";
    }
}
else
{
    $utility->MessageBox("Please select a file to upload.");
}
```

## The Problem

This part in the PHP code outputs a "success statement" which has a link ("Proceed to final step"). This link is not clickable.

```
if ($update_TPC)
{
    echo "<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><span class='SuccessText'>File uploaded successfully. You're almost done.</span><br /><br /><a href='../step4/'>Proceed to final step</a>";
}
```

## What I have tried so far (none worked)

1. Used iframes as can be seen in the code.
2. In my css file, added Z-index: 10; separately to both the class .SuccessText and the containing div (#Image_Upload_Instructions)

## Here is the weirdest part (clue for you smart people)

When I view the page source after the file has been processed and the Success message is displayed, I can't see the success message within the iframe.

Please help! I have been at this for 2 nights now, no luck.

## Here is the CSS for your reference:

```css
#InitStepDisplay_Stretched {
    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
    min-height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
    background-color: #FFFFEF;
}
#InitStepDisplay_Stretched td {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
#Image_Upload_Instructions {
    position: fixed;
    top: 280px;
    left: 290px;
    height: 700px;
    width: 440px;
    z-index: 10;
}
#InitStepDisplay_Stretched a {
    background-color: #3F8FCA;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#InitStepDisplay_Stretched a:visited {
    background-color: #3F8FCA;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#InitStepDisplay_Stretched a:hover {
    background-color: #3F74BF;
    color: #DEEFEA;
}
#InitStepDisplay_Stretched a:active {
    background-color: #3F8FCA;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#InitStepDisplay_Stretched ul {
    list-style: circle;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.PictureDisplayInit {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 470px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px dashed #CFCFCF;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.Stretch { max-width:200px; max-height:200px; width:auto; height:auto; }

.FileInput {
    padding: 10px 5px;
    width: 440px;
    border: 1px solid #CFCFCF;  
}
```

Comment: try to run html validator on your result page

Comment: +1 for complete and neat post

Comment: @eicto I will try that. However, I don't think there is an issue with the html. It's probably a z-index issue that I can't figure out.

Comment: in chrome dev tools open Elements tab, right click on body tag, copy as html and paste to jsfiddle, add also your css to fiddle, see if problem still here, let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped the contents of the echo statement in a div and the link was clickable.

```
if ($update_TPC)
{
    echo "<div><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><span class='SuccessText'>File uploaded successfully. You're almost done.</span><br /><br /><a href='../step4/'>Proceed to final step</a></div>";
}
```

Comment: If someone can please explain to me why this may have worked, I would be very much obliged.

Answer (score -1):

You can't have ../ in an href. It won't see it as a link. It has to be either /location.php or a full http://blah.com link. That link is not a valid one.

Comment: That's not true, `../foo.bar` is a valid relative URL, that references to a resource named `foo.bar` one directory above the current one.

Comment: Hi mcrtr, I second what CBroe said. I used a link like www.googl.com and it would still be unclickable. I am thinking it's a z-index issue.